# How to add or redefine operator in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, operator-keyword, inequality, redefine

I debug one code some hours and finally found that it uses `!=` operator while my eyes scanning at code reads it as `=`. I always use `<>` operator in *Pascal* many years before. Now I must write and debug in **C** to make code reusable by community. So I tried to define `<>` as `!=` in following commands:

```
#define <> !=
#define "<>" "!="
```

But it did not work. I tried to search on the web, but only I found results about C++ or C# but I need it for **C**.
Is there any chances for write reusable **C** code using `<>` as inequality operator? (I assume other `normal` users can auto-replace `<>` to `!=`, but code should compile on other systems also without modification, i.e., with `<>`).
I use Linux (*gcc*).

Comment: That would be an invalid preprocessor macro name. If you want to write understandable C code then *code to the standard*. Don't use things like this.

Comment: Let's make a parallel with real languages. Say you wan't to learn spanish. In spanish, a cat is `un gato`, but as a matter of fact, you don't like the word `gato` so you want to keep using the good old english `cat` instead. You can see the pure evil under the thing ;)

Comment: Even if you could do this it would be a very bad idea ... make your code readable by others.

Comment: It's bizarre that people here are talking about operator overloading, which has nothing to do with this, as <> is not an operator in C or C++.

Comment: Hi Friends, thank you for answers. I now know that what i want is called `overload`, not `redefine` operator (so i able now to find other similar topics already answered). And i now see why it is bad. I will try to `#define NEQ !=`, _NEQ_ looks useful. But i will do it only locally, and will replace things to standard when share the code. Sorry again for my strange and mad question!

Comment: I also found a _standard_ way to make some operators in C more meaningful: it is part of *ISO646*, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_alternative_tokens), and provided by `iso646.h` from **C standard library**.

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't have operator overloading. Period. Use a different programming language, if you require that feature.

Answer (score 2):

The operators characters cannot be used in the name of *any* object, i.e. a preprocessor macro (in your case), variable name, function name ...
So basically, you can't do such a thing. You can see my comment to see why it was a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can't overload operator in c.

Answer (score 1):

As previousl stated, there are no operator overloading in C (it was introduced in C++ only)
However, you still have the option to automatically generate your files with `<>` replaced by `!=` during your compilation process.

Comment: Although it is still possible (one can think of a `sed` command run prior to compilation), it is a _very_ bad idea

Comment: I do agree. It's just the only solution that came to my mind. If he really need it, it's a way... until someone have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you build your program and one of the following line is included in your c code

```
#define <> !=
#define "<>" "!="
```

then you will get a compilation error:

```
error: macro names must be identifiers
```

that means that the name of your macro should start with a letter and even there is a limitation in the use of some special charachters in the name of the macro.

may be you can use another name for your macro like:

```
#define NEQ !=
```

This is allowed